# Logstash Grok Pattern for mysql logs

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

This is the sample log pattern I'm parsing. I'm using grok but it's not exactly as what I expected

```
180528 8:46:26 2 Query  SELECT 1
```

To parse this log my grok pattern is

```
%{NUMBER:date} %{NOTSPACE:time}%{INT:pid}%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

and output for this in grok debugger is

```
> {   "date": [
>     [
>       "180528"
>     ]   ],   "time": [
>     [
>       "8:46:2"
>     ]   ],   "pid": [
>     [
>       "6"
>     ]   ],   "message": [
>     [
>       " 2 Query\tSELECT 1"
>     ]   ] }
```

If you observe in the output, pid is being extracted from time and actual pid which is 2 is being merged in the message. Not sure what went wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just match your time with `TIME` pattern instead? it doesn't make sense to match it with `NOTSPACE` which equals to `\S+`, and matches any non-whitespace character (equal to `[^\r\n\t\f\v ]`)

You can use `TIME` pattern for your time value and `INT` for `pid` as follows,

```
%{NUMBER:date}\s%{TIME:time}\s%{INT:pid}\s%{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

This will give you,

```
{
  "date": [
    [
      "180528"
    ]
  ],
  "BASE10NUM": [
    [
      "180528"
    ]
  ],
  "time": [
    [
      "8:46:26"
    ]
  ],
  "HOUR": [
    [
      "8"
    ]
  ],
  "MINUTE": [
    [
      "46"
    ]
  ],
  "SECOND": [
    [
      "26"
    ]
  ],
  "pid": [
    [
      "2"
    ]
  ],
  "message": [
    [
      "Query  SELECT 1"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: it worked. Thank you. I used time as well before but missed the /s.